# Kotlin Android extensions and retained fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am using [Kotlin Android extensions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) in my project and I came across some behavior that I am unable to understand. I use this code to retain my fragment in the activity:

```
val fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("hello") ?: HelloFragment()
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "hello")
               .commit()
```

This is the retained `Fragment`:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.hello.*

public class HelloFragment : Fragment() {
    val text = "Hello world!"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super<Fragment>.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setRetainInstance(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.hello, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super<Fragment>.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        text_view.setText(text) // <- does not work when retained
    }
}
```

and its XML layout **hello.xml**:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Everything works as expected – the `text_view.setText()` displays *Hello world!* on screen on the first launch. But when you rotate the screen the `text_view.setText()` does not work. This is weird because `text_view` is not nullable and has to reffer to some view. If you remove `setRetainInstance(true)` and leave the fragment recreate every time this problem disappears. Any thoughts what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPD:** The issue is fixed now. You don't have to call `clearFindViewByIdCache()` manually anymore.

`View` cache is not cleared after calling `onDestroyView()`. There is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8073).

For now, you can explicitly invoke `clearFindViewByIdCache()` in `onDestroyView()` to clear the cache. This method is part of the `synthetic` package so you have to import it

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.*
```

Comment: The issue is fixed now. see @greenspand answer below

Answer (score 7):

I have found the answer myself. The `Fragment` class does not inflate the layout directly – it has property `view: View?` which holds it. This should be pretty obvious since it is created with `onCreateView`. In order to access the properties within the `view` you have to set the import

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.hello.view.*
```

and then access the properties as follows

```
view?.text_view?.setText(text)
```

Note that these properties are nullable.

Comment: Do we always have to use clearFindViewByIdCache() if we use import kotlinx.android.synthetic.* in our fragments???

Comment: You shouldn't need `clearFindViewByIdCache()` anymore according to [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33150682/4584675) to this question.

Answer (score 7):

Just to clarify. The issue is fixed now. You don't have to pass clearFindViewByIdCache() anylonger. Please see issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FKT-8073